# How I can select * from a table of a particular date ignoring the time

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, datetime

I want to select * from the table where date= particular date, but my sql column is in date and time format. how i can retrieve the date of particular date ignoring the time.

Comment: what's your (R)DBMS ?

Comment: What [RDBMS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relational_database_management_system) you are using? `RDBMS` stands for *Relational Database Management System*. `RDBMS is the basis for SQL`, and for all modern database systems like MS SQL Server, IBM DB2, Oracle, MySQL, etc...

Comment: waht have you tied so far ? What Database are you using ? ... you'll have to deal with date formating and conversion function and conversion patterns, this stuff is dbms specific.

Answer (score 0):

If you are on sql-server 2008 or above, you could use `convert` function to convert `datetime type` *to* `date type` as below.

```
select * 
from yourtable
where convert(date, yourDateTimeCol) = yourDate
```